# How Hystrix communicate with Eureka?

Tags: netflix, hystrix, netflix-eureka

I've seen a lot examples of projects, where both Hystrix and Eureka are used.
It would be nice if someone could explain to me how they both communicate.
Maybe It's a wrong build question, but I would like to know why there is both hystrix and eureka on the projects.

Comment: My current observation is that Eureka provides valid url for some service and Hystrix is property using Service client with that url.Is it correct ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eureka and Hystrix are two different services, both developed by Netflix.

`Eureka` provides some kind of `elastic load balancer`. It has a server part (where the clients get registered), and a client one. The clients register themselves in the server by sending heartbeats, and also get the registry information from the server in order to know where the services (other clients) it needs are located (as a client can also be a service). Have a look at the [eureka wiki](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Eureka-at-a-glance) for a much better explanation.

`Hystrix` is on the other hand an implementation of the `Circuit Breaker Pattern` (if you do not know what this is, buy the `Release It` book right now). It basically provides a way of controlling your "expensive" calls (normally to a remote system) by wrapping them. If the remote system is not available, or the calls are taking too long, Hystrix will deliver you a "failure" (or configured fallback) response immediately instead of keeping you blocked waiting for a response that will not come. The [hystrix page](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix) explains it much better.

Comment: Right, eureka and hystrix don't talk to each other.